# Can't get transaction hash from signAndSend of Polkadot.js

Tags: transactions, transfer, token, hash

I'm new and I'm trying to get the transaction hash but I'm only getting `undefined`. I used this [tutorial](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/start/api.tx.subs/) and [this](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/extension/usage/) and below is my code.

```
const txHash = await polkadot.tx.balances
  .transfer('5F1pZe.....GmZRSZuK', 100000000000)
  .signAndSend(SENDER, { signer: injector.signer }, (status) => {

        if (status.isInBlock) {
            console.log(`Completed at block hash #${status.isInBlock}`);
        } else {
            console.log(`Current status: ${status.type}`);
        }


    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(':( transaction failed', error);
    });

console.log("Submitted with hash", txHash.hash);
```

I'm getting `undefined` for `txHash.hash`, `status.type`. I have another code that works but I wonder what's wrong with the above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The txhash is only returned when you use the non-subscribe form.

In code for the non-sub form -

```js
// don't subscribe, txhash is returned
const txHash = await polkadot.tx.balances
  .transfer('5F1pZe.....GmZRSZuK', 100000000000)
  .signAndSend(SENDER, { signer: injector.signer });

console.log(txhash);
```

And for the subscription form -

```js
// subscription, unsub is returned, txHash internal
const unsub = await polkadot.tx.balances
  .transfer('5F1pZe.....GmZRSZuK', 100000000000)
  .signAndSend(SENDER, { signer: injector.signer }, (status) => {
    console.log(status.txHash);
  });

// unsubscribe
unsub();
```